# unable to project points on the map in R

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

I'm new to maps with R. I tried to create a basic map with R and try to project few points on it. Unfortunately it didn't work. I could create the map, but geom_point object that I try to project is not showing up in the map. Any help is appreciated.

```
require(pacman)
library(cowplot)
pacman::p_load(RColorBrewer, ggspatial, raster,colorspace, ggpubr)
SWE       <- getData('GADM', country='Sweden', level=1) %>% st_as_sf() #Sweden map

sites <- data.frame(longitude = c(63.58,63.62), latitude = c(19.018, 19.9222))  #dataframe of points that try to overlay on the map. 

B <- ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data= SWE)+
  geom_point(data = sites, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 4, 
             shape = 23, fill = "darkred")+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(18,22), ylim = c(62.5 ,64),expand = FALSE)+
  geom_point(data = sites2, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 4, 
             shape = 23, fill = "darkred")+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: What is `sites2`?

Comment: You need to match the variable names in your geom to those in your dataframe. ("long" vs. "longitude" etc.)